# how do I uninstall Xcode 5.1.1 completely?

Tags: xcode, osx-mavericks, uninstallation

i'm running mavericks and want to remove Xcode 5.1.1 so i can use more powerful tools. I see that there are some bloatware programs out there for uninstalling Xcode 5.1.1 but none of them really seem credible. Please help!

Comment: what's the problem if you simply remove the XCode.app?

Comment: delete XCode.app since everything SDK and stuff is in this app. And don't forget ~/Library/Developer.

Comment: @Tony J Stark If You have not noticed, upon installing new SDK It also takes some time to install additional components required for the SDK. Thus - it probably has some stuff installed or updated elsewhere in computer.

Comment: i was worried about the other stuff it installed. I guess there isn't really a quick and easy way to just remove it completely.

Answer (score 1):

A Mac application I can recommend (since I am using it myself) is *[CleanMyMac](http://cleanmymac.com)*. It has several cleaning features and also the deinstallation of applications is possible. 
It is paid, however there is a trial version and if you only need it once then that should work.

[Note: I do not have any relation with the product if people may doubt, I just like and recommend it since it really does what it should and fits your needs.]

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Dont be so afraid in life dude :)

Comment: Afraid? Nah... I just know how people love to falsely allege and I want to prevent that. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck using this application for complete removal: http://www.appzapper.com/  (I'm not affiliated with them.  It's just a good tool.)